# C# get the directory name from the DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, exception

I made an application that search for some files in some directories. When a directory isn't there it throws the `DirectoryNotFoundException`. I catch that exception but it doesn't have a `DirectoryName` property or something like that like the `FileNotFoundException` (FileName). How can I find the Directory Name from the exception properties?

Comment: The Directory doesn't exist if you got the DirectoryNotFoundException, you certainly aren't going to find the Directory Name if the directory doesn't exist.  Am I misunderstanding the question maybe?

Comment: @Caimen: Which directory doesn't exist?

Comment: Do you want the name it attempted to find?

Comment: @Caimen The OP is saying that the exception should _know_ what directory was checked (as apparently the FileNotFoundException knows which file was checked).

Comment: Don't you have the path of the file you were looking for anyway?

Comment: Why don't you have a variable `currentDirectory`? If this directory-name can't be found, you can get the name from it.

Comment: This is not necessarily true in the catching code. The fact that it's an exception already means it can be caught very far away from where it was thrown. Passing around that variable is the wrong approach.

Comment: @Greg: But you could catch that exception, add the directory-path to it(f.e. with a custom exception) and rethrow it.

Comment: You might not have the directory path available even at the first place you can catch the exception. Is he throwing the exception himseld or is he calling someone else's library? It's good to ask, but we shouldn't assume he can do so.

Comment: If what Greg described is true, you can go to Debug -> Exceptions, then check the "Thrown" box for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". This will take you right to an exception when it happens, instead of waiting to get caught.

Comment: That's a good one-off solution (and likely all the OP needs -- you might want to post that as an answer). In more general terms, what would be the proper way to be able to catch such an exception and show a friendly error to the user in produciton code? (Perhaps any such library should make sure it passes enough information out with its exceptions? What happens if it doesn't? Are we just stuck?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to natively do this.

Add this class somewhere to your project:

```
public static class DirectoryNotFoundExceptionExtentions
{
    public static string GetPath(this DirectoryNotFoundException dnfe)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex pathMatcher = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[^']+");
        return pathMatcher.Matches(dnfe.Message)[1].Value;
    }
}
```

Catch the exception and use the type extension like this:

```
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dnfe)
{
   Console.WriteLine(dnfe.GetPath()); 
}
```

Comment: In my case I had to look for double quotes: ex.Message.Split(new[] { '"', '\'' })[1]

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a hack, but you can extract the path from the `Message` property. As for me, I would prefer to check if the directory exists first, by using the `Directory.Exists` method.

```
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
{
    // Result will be: Could not find a part of the path "C:\incorrect\path".
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

    // Result will be: C:\incorrect\path
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message
        .Replace("Could not find a part of the path \"", "")
        .Replace("\".", ""));
}
```

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directorynotfoundexception.aspx it looks like the path does indeed appear in the `Message` property.

Comment: +1 - I would call that a hack, since it is would fail if the application is running in a different culture. This would be a good solution, though, for any occasions in which the culture is known beforehand. (Checking Directory.Exists is worse hack, since that can fail under any circumstance, which means there are two different error conditions for the same problem!)

Comment: Keep in mind that, generally, the proper way to log an exception is not by using its message, but by calling `Exception.ToString()` which contains the message plus other useful information.

Comment: You can generalize the hack into a much more epic hack by using a giant case statement to conditionally parse for every possible culture/loc. As the default case, simply throw an exception: `throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Could not find directory name in string \"" + e.Message + "\"");`

Answer (score 2):

It is a little inconsistent that `FileNotFoundException` has the file name, but `DirectoryNotFoundException` doesn't have the directory name, isn't it?

Here's a work around: Before you throw the exception, associate the errant directory name using Exception's `Data` property.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately before you attempt to find files in a directory, save the name of the directory in a variable. Then begin a try block for the code that looks in that directory. You now have the directory name available should that block of code throw.

For example:

```
// ... somewhere in some method that's about to search a directory.

var dirName = directories[i]; // or something -- how do you get it before you pass it to DirectoryInfo?

try
{
    SearchDirectory(dirName); // or a block of code that does the work
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // at this point, you know dirName. You can log it, add it to a list of erroring
    // directories, or whatever. You could throw here, or swallow the error after logging it, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that it exists first with Directory.Exists

Comment: What if it's not in his code? If he's the one trying to use the directory, he probably already has the directory name, so its a moot point in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to stomp this one bug in your IDE, then you can try doing this:

In Visual Studio, go to `Debug -> Exceptions`, then check the `Thrown` box for `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`. This will take you right to an exception when it happens, instead of waiting to get caught.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to dig up an old post, but as other has said it is pretty stupid that DirectoryNotFoundException does not have the directory as a property when FileNotFoundException does.

I've put it in as feature request for .NET:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4472498-directorynotfoundexception-should-expose-the-name-

Answer (score 0):

The format of the Message member of the DirectoryNotFoundException thrown from most Directory class methods is "Directory 'input' not found.". It shouldn't be hard to extract the input from this string.

Question thou, why would you need to get the input parameter from the exception if you're the one invoking the method with that exact parameter?